# Round UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a custom table view cell with an image view. I'm trying to make the image view circular but it is not circular and I can't pinpoint the issue.

```
import UIKit

class LegislatorImageCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var repImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var repOfficeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var repNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var repPartyLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        repOfficeLabel.textColor = .white
        repNameLabel.textColor = .white
        repPartyLabel.textColor = .white

        repImageView.layer.cornerRadius = repImageView.frame.height / 2
        repImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        repImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        repImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        repImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        print("HEIGHT: \(repImageView.frame.height)")
        print("WIDTH: \(repImageView.frame.width)")
        print("CORNER RADIUS: \(repImageView.layer.cornerRadius)")
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

Here are the results of the print statements.

```
HEIGHT: 125.0
WIDTH: 125.0
CORNER RADIUS: 62.5
```

[image]

Comment: try to add `repImageView.layer.masksToBounds = false`

Comment: Are you sure that the imageview height is equals to its width?

Comment: @AhmadF Yes. I print both values as is mentioned in my question.

Comment: Then it should work fine, make sure that you are not editing the radius somewhere else in your code, such as `cellForRowAt`, `didMoveToWindow`, `layoutSubviews` etc...

Comment: Did you find the answer. I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the break point at

```
 repImageView.layer.cornerRadius = repImageView.frame.height / 2
```

and print the `repImageView.frame.height`. You will realise that the code is doing what it is supposed to do. Setting the corner radius to half of current height.

The problem is the height has not been updated yet properly. 
Move your code to `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` . That should fix the problem. Or if you know the final height/width of image view. Just set it directly there to be

```
whateverHeight / 2
```

Comment: Moving it to layoutSubviews() did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Move this code: `repImageView.layer.cornerRadius = repImageView.frame.height / 2` to `updateConstraints` method.

Comment: This did not fix the issue.

Comment: @raginggoat do you call `super.updateConstraints`, right?

Comment: override func updateConstraints() {
        super.updateConstraints()
        repImageView.layer.cornerRadius = repImageView.frame.height / 2
    }

Comment: @raginggoat In your screenshot, the width is not equal to the height and thus here is a not corrected corner radius. I imagine that in your xib file the width and height have the same size and you see this size in `awakeFromNib` method. Can you print the size in `updateConstraints`?

Comment: When I print them in updateConstraints(), I get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Autolayout hasn't given the view its size yet. Call `self.setNeedsLayout()` and `self.layoutIfNeeded()` first before using the view's frame.

Comment: This did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Code you provided isn't causing your issue. Issue appears because view layout is updated after `awakeFromNib`, after `image` is set increasing your `UIImage` width. You have to apply constraints to your `repImageView`; apply same value to height and width constraints, or apply ratio constraint to preserve 1:1 proportion of `repImageView`. Also consider moving your code from `awakeFromNib` to `layoutSubviews`, to be executed every time layout is updated.

Comment: When I set the height and width constraints  in IB on the image view and move the code to layoutSubviews(), I get the same result and a message saying it will attempt to recover by breaking the width constraint.

Comment: means that you have some other constraints forcing your image view width. can you provide more info (which constraints you have)?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, late post but I'm pretty sure this is the answer for others viewing:

You are setting the imageView to change the curvature to a circle, and when you set it the imageView has a 1:1 frame. However, when you then set the photo on the imageView (which happens after the awakeFromNib is called), you have 'Scale to Fill' set. What this does is it resizes the imageView to prefer the size of the image > the autoLayout ratio. What you most likely want to do is in the storyboard set your imageView to 'Aspect Fill', and it will respect the ratio of the imageView > the image's preferred ratio (though this may distort the image). You can use 'Aspect Fit' to keep the ratio and not distort, though your imageView might then have transparent space.